# How to unset a sub-array mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Hey how do you $unset a sub-array in mongodb without removing the parent array.

Here is the query I am running using mongoose:

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate(
    req.signedCookies.userid,
    {
        $addToSet: {
            friend: { 
                friendId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.friend),
                date_added: new Date()
            }
        },
        $unset: {
            notifications: {
                receivedRequest: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.signedCookies.userid)
            }
        }
    }
);
```

However, this removes the whole notifications array...

Comment: sub-array or sub document?

Comment: I have an array called notifications that has arrays in them that include a userid, date of request

Comment: You might want to write a program to loop through. It doesn't seem to be possible to use one query for right now, please checkout https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243

Comment: so you cannot select sub-documents? Can I do a $pull on each sub-document in the sub-array?

Answer (score 0):

You want to unset only a field:

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate(
    req.signedCookies.userid,
    {
        $addToSet: {
            friend: {
                friendId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.friend),
                date_added: new Date()
            }
        },
        $unset: { 'notifications.receivedRequest': " " }
    }
);
```